# Today's equivalent of a cake of yeast

Tags: yeast

I came across one of my mother's cookbooks from 1954.  A lot of the baked goods call for "1 cake of yeast".  What would be the equivalent of this in today's supermarket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* find fresh cake yeast in grocery stores, but it's much less common than active dry yeast granulates.

1 cake of fresh yeast is approximately the same as 1 envelope/packet of active dry yeast. 1 packet usually equals about 2¼ teaspoons, or ¼ ounce, or 7 grams of active dry yeast granules.